# How to select class from lists of classes based on key – "like" in dicts?

Tags: python, class, dictionary

I have a list of classes in my code and I want to access them based on a 'key' of a dictionary, in a loop, so I am trying to understand which could be the most appropriate way to do it. I am trying to think, if maybe I associate an attribute to the `class`, like
`Class.key`, then maybe I can iterate among my elements, but maybe I am just approaching the problem the wrong way.

To be more clear, this is just a rough example. If my `dict` is:

```
dict = {'A': 'blue', 'B': 'apple', 'C': 'dog'}
```

and my list of classes:

```
listOfClasses = [Class_A, Class_B, Class_C]
```

I would like to operate in such a way that:

```
for key in dict:
    print(key, dict[key])
    print(key, ---"something like: Class.value if Class.key == key" ---)
```

Maybe the question is confusing, or stupid, or maybe I am just approaching the wrong way and should create a `dict` of classes, (if it is possible?). Just need a piece of advice I guess.

Comment: You can create another dict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The classes themselves are python objects, and therefore valid dictionary values.

```
class ClassA:
    pass

class ClassB:
    pass

class ClassC:
    pass

class_registry = {
    'A': ClassA,
    'B': ClassB,
    'C': ClassC,
}

for name, cls in class_registry.items():
    print (name, cls.__name__)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
for cls in listOfClasses:
    print(cls.value)
```